# NetBeans C++ can not create project

Tags: c++, netbeans

Every time I try to create a project in Netbeans C++ it is Validating but nothing more. I get an notifications which says: 
Unexpected Exception 
Priority: Silent Category: Error
java.lan.NullPointerException

Or it says:
The syntax for filename, directory or volume label is wron (I have translated it from german)

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of NetBeans?

Comment: You mentioned German... Are there any unusual characters in the path to the project?

Comment: Version 8.0.2. No nothing unusual. Looks like this: C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects

Comment: Can you post the log entry?